# Как запустить готовое AngularJS приложение

Tags: angularjs

При попытке запустить сервер с готовым приложением AngularJS по команде `ng serve`
консоль выдает кучу ошибок такого типа

> Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from
>   "C:\Users\Goldberg\Desktop\руля\backend". Error: Could not find
>   module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from
>   "C:\Users\Goldberg\Desktop\руля\backend".
>       at Object.resolve (C:\Users\Goldberg\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node\resolve.js:141:11)
>       at Observable.rxjs_1.Observable [as _subscribe] (C:\Users\Goldberg\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\src\architect.js:132:40)
>       at Observable._trySubscribe (C:\Users\Goldberg\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:43:25)
>       at Observable.subscribe (C:\Users\Goldberg\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:29:22)
>       at DoOperator.call (C:\Users\Goldberg\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\tap.js:29:23)
>       at Observable.subscribe (C:\Users\Goldberg\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:24:22)
>       at C:\Users\Goldberg\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\util\subscribeTo.js:22:31
>       at Object.subscribeToResult (C:\Users\Goldberg\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\util\subscribeToResult.js:7:45)
>       at MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (C:\Users\Goldberg\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:75:38)
>       at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (C:\Users\Goldberg\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:72:14)

При этом,новое приложение отлично создается командой `ng new` и спокойно запускается командой `ng serve`
В чем может быть причина ?

Comment: в отсутствии файла angular.json

Comment: А можно его добавить уже в существующее приложение ?Я вроде добавил,но ничего не изменилось

Comment: возможно добавил не в ту папку

Comment: там есть 2 папки: frontend и backend, в backend node_modules,в frontend e2e,gulp,src и тд папки,вопрос в какую папку добавить angular и в какой папке прописать ng serve или может что другое ?

Comment: он должен быть в папке внутри которой ты ng serve вызываешь

Comment: отредактировал тему,теперь такие ошибки выдает

Comment: Возможно, надо выполнить `npm install`?